# Order by and group by together in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I want result with `group by(project_id and posted_as)` and `order by created_at(timestamp)`
My query is

```
SELECT *, MAX(created_at) FROM `property_basic_info` 
     GROUP BY project_id,posting_as ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

but did not get expected result .
I have searched lot but did not get result
please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your expected result? In fact,your sql won't run correctly and it will show error

Comment: `SELECT *, ..` is wrong (incomplete grouping). Must be `SELECT project_id, posting_as, MAX(created_at) ..`

Comment: * call many ids that's used in another sql

Comment: Actually problem is this .when i used group by among same two project_id last one is removed that's why our result become mismatch , because order by call after group by .  Are you getting my point